# How to set TCP socket options to let it send ACK/RST in handshaking?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, operating-system

I notice that HAProxy's probing mechanism is like:

```
Client -> [SYN]     -> Server
Client <- [ACK/SYN] <- Server
Client -> [ACK/RST] -> Server
```

After browsing the source codes of HAProxy, I think they are not modifying the network stack behavior and achieve that in user-mode. So I guess that's a trick of socket options. Could you please give me some hints of it?

Comment: Why do you want to send an `RST` to reset (disconnect) immediately? What is the actual problem you're supposed to solve?

Comment: I want to figure out and simulate the HAProxy behavior (for some reasons). XD

Comment: But the C source codes of it are too too complex..

Comment: Your flow diagram is incorrect. The client sends SYN to the server; the server sends SYN-ACK to the client; the client sends ACK to the server. Not the other way around. Your question is unclear.

Comment: My flow diagram is from Wireshark and it is really like that.

Comment: Your flow diagram is back to front, whatever Wireshark may say, but it certainly doesn't show 'server' and 'client': it shows IP addresses. In this case what you are describing as 'server' is clearly the client, and *vice versa.*.

Comment: It doesn't matter who is server or who is client, since TCP is end-to-end.

Comment: TCP has a listening socket, at the server, and an actively connected socket, at the client. 'End to end' is both meaningless and irrelevant. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I see. I have modified my question details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated described behavior with TCP Fast Open. When `connect()` is used, TCP client(who you marked as *Server*) will wait for SYN-ACK and reply with ACK.

Here is my example:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
    
int main() {
        int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        struct sockaddr_in sai;
        sai.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sai.sin_port = htons(1234);
        sai.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

        struct linger sl;
        sl.l_onoff = 1;         /* non-zero value enables linger option in kernel */
        sl.l_linger = 0;        /* timeout interval in seconds */
        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &sl, sizeof(sl));

        int ret = sendto(sock, NULL, 0, MSG_FASTOPEN | MSG_MORE, &sai, sizeof(sai));
        if(ret == -1) {
                //Probing or TFO failed
                //If TFO failed, try connect()
        }
        close(sock);
}
```

Comment: From Wireshark, your codes seem like:
```
Client -> [SYN]     -> Server
Client <- [ACK/SYN] <- Server
Client -> [ACK] -> Server
Client -> [FIN,ACK] -> Server
...
```
It still has more than 3 packets...

Comment: Maybe you have TFO disabled? Maybe Nagle is globally disabled?

Comment: By the way you can mark answer as accepted by clicking at check mark.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very reasonable question as to how to do this for the purposes of doing health checks.  And it is not at all obvious how to do so.

I don't know how to get the Syn, Syn-Ack, Ack-Rst using normal socket operations; the closest I can think of is to open the connection and then immediately close it with SO_LINGER interval of 0.

But even if you could duplicate it, there is still the problem that the user space application wants to quickly learn if the Syn-Ack arrives or not (a normal TCP connection would retransmit the Syn if there was no reply, and eventually give up after quite a long time compared to how fast you want to get an answer to your health check). Since all of this is handled in the kernel TCP implementation, I don't think there is any way to quickly know that the Syn-Ack has arrived.  Which leads me to believe that this is not being accomplished with normal socket operations .

What I would do is construct a Syn packet in the user space application and send it using a raw socket.  Use Iptables/netfilter to send the Syn-Ack reply to user space. If the Syn-Ack arrives in time your health check passes.  And when it arrives the kernel TCP stack  will also see it (unless your use of Iptables/netfilter prevents it) and immediately reply with a reset (because it doesn't know about the connection).